# Exception after DAO-operation using WebSphere-8 / Spring 4 / Hibernate 4.3

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jta, websphere-8

My WebSphere 8 driven portlet uses Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.3 over JPA. I have a JTA data source. This is my setup:

persistence.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  >
      <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
          <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
          <jta-data-source>jdbc/mydb</jta-data-source>
          <properties>
              <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform" />
              <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory" />
              <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
          </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

my-portlet.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When my DAO-method is called, an exceptions are thrown:

```
00000090 RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
   at com.ibm.ws.uow.ComponentContextSynchronizationWrapper.beforeCompletion(ComponentContextSynchronizationWrapper.java:65)
```

and

```
(... servlet and portlet specific exceptions ...)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: UOWManager transaction processing failed; nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: javax.transaction.RollbackException
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
```

This is my DAO-class:

```
  @Repository("myDao")
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public class HibernateMyEntityDao implements MyEntityDao
  {
     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     public Session getSession()
     {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
     }

     @Transactional
     public List<MyEntity> findActive()
     {
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
        crit.setFirstResult(0);
        crit.setFetchSize(10);
        crit.add(Restrictions.le("start", date));
        crit.add(Restrictions.gt("end", date));
        return crit.list();
     }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `IncompatibleClassChangeError` normally indicates that the dependency versions are incorrect. You can read more about it [here](http://craftingjava.blogspot.com/2012/08/javalangincompatibleclasschangeerror.html) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/incompatibleclasschangeerror-jobdetailbean-has-interface-org-quartz-jobdetail-as-super-class/).

It is probable that the combination of websphere 8, spring 4 and hibernate 4.3 are not compatible with each other. My guess is on hibernate 4.3 and websphere 8 not being compatible. Did you try with slightly older versions of spring and hibernate?

Comment: Thanks! WebSphere 8 ships with OpenJPA 2.1. The version number "2.1" made me believe that JPA 2.1 is implemented. So I reasoned that WebSphere 8 supports JPA 2.1. But this is wrong: OpenJPA 2.1 implements JPA 2.0, WebSphere 8 only supports JPA 2.0 and as Hibernate 4.3 implements JPA 2.1, I have to use Hibernate 4.2